# Screenshots to video using ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-encoding

I have screenshots that are taken .25 seconds apart, that I'm trying to combine into a video. No matter what I try it ends up too fast or too slow/choppy. I've tried the following commands.

`ffmpeg -framerate 7.5 -i ./T1-%d.png -dn -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p outfile.mkv`

`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i ./T1-%d.png -r 4 -dn -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "setpts=4.0*PTS" outfile.mkv`

`ffmpeg -i ./T1-%d.png -r 30 -dn -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 outfile.mkv`

Just looking to combine these into as smooth a video as possible.

Comment: If they were taken .25 seconds apart, then the command should be `ffmpeg -framerate 4 -i ./T1-%d.png -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p outfile.mkv`

Comment: I agree with the framerate parameters set to 4 (1/4 = 0.25 seconds).